# Run time error in spoj's prime1 solution in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

I am able to get the correct outputs on my Ubuntu system but getting run time error when i submit the solution.I am using python3.4 for the same.Here is my source code.

```
t=int(input())
i=0
while(i!=t):
    list=[2]
    number=3
    counter=0
    limit1=int(input(""))
    limit=int(input(""))
    while(number<=int(limit)):
        for a in list:
            if(number%a==0):
                counter+=1
                break;
        if(counter==0):
            list.append(number)
        else:
            counter=0
        number+=1
    for num in list:
        if(num>=limit1):
            print(num)
    i+=1
```

I want to know why is it so that on my own system i am getting correct answer and on the online judge getting run time error.

Comment: for the love of god, put some spacing in between your assignments and statements, also don't use list as a variable name. You don't need `;` or parens around statements. Apart from that where exactly are you running it?

Comment: On sphere online judge

Comment: how are you running it locally?

Comment: post the link to the problem

Comment: @PadraicCunningham On Ubuntu i am running this code

Comment: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

Comment: your code may just be too slow for large values, I see a sieve of Eratosthenes  being mentioned in the comments http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: But then that should be not run time error

Comment: well I can almost guarantee you that your algorithm is too inefficient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63806/discussion-between-user2738777-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: Does the site give you the traceback with line number of the problem, and the text of the exception message?  If so, post.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy No,it just gives information about result,time and memory and with this code it is runtime error, 0.01 and 8.5M.